# Average individual consumption growth vs average aggregate consumption growth

Tags: stochastic-discount, euler

Consumption growth is an essential thing in most asset pricing models and usually the Euler equation defines the return of an asset as a covariance between consumption frowth and the cash-flows of that asset.

I am trying to understand what drives differences between average individual consumption growth and average aggregate consumption growth.

Let's assume there are $N$ agents and $T$ time periods and $K$ economies. There is a matrix $C_k$ which stores the consumption of each agent $n$ and each time period $t$ for each economy $k$. This is a $[T \times N]$ matrix.

\begin{equation}
C_k = \begin{bmatrix}
c_{k,1,1} & c_{k,2,1}  & ...  & c_{k,N,1}  \\ 
c_{k,1,2} & c_{k,2,2}  & ...  & c_{k,N,2}  \\ 
... & ... & ... & ...  \\ 
c_{k,1,T} & c_{k,2,T}  & ...  & c_{k,N,T}  \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

So $c_{k,i,t}$ is the consumption of agent $i$ at time $t$ in economy $k$.

Now I can compute each agent's individual consumption growth $\Delta c$:

\begin{equation}
\Delta C_k = \begin{bmatrix}
\Delta c_{k,1,2} & \Delta c_{k,2,2}  & ...  & \Delta c_{k,N,2}  \\ 
\Delta c_{k,1,3} & \Delta c_{k,2,3}  & ...  & \Delta c_{k,N,3}  \\ 
... & ... & ... & ...  \\ 
\Delta c_{k,1,T} & \Delta c_{k,2,T}  & ...  & \Delta c_{k,N,T}  \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Where $\Delta c_{k,n,t} \equiv ln(\frac{c_{k,n,t}}{c_{k,n,t-1}})$.

So the average individual consumption growth across all economies, time periods and agents is:

\begin{equation}
Average IndividualConsumptionGrowth=\sum^K_{k=1} \sum^N_{n=1} \sum^T_{t=2} \frac{\Delta c_{k,n,t}}{K \times N \times (T-1)}
\end{equation}

Now I also want average aggregate consumption growth. First we need a vector of aggregate consumption which is just the sum of individual consumptions.

\begin{equation}
C^{agg}_k = \begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{n=1}^N c_{k,n,1}  \\ 
\sum_{n=1}^N c_{k,n,2}  \\ 
...   \\ 
\sum_{n=1}^N c_{k,n,T} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Which gives aggregate consumption growth as:

\begin{equation}
\Delta C^{agg}_k  = \begin{bmatrix}
\Delta \sum_{n=1}^N c_{k,n,2}  \\ 
\Delta \sum_{n=1}^N c_{k,n,3}  \\ 
...   \\ 
\Delta \sum_{n=1}^N c_{k,n,T} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Where $\Delta \sum_{n=1}^N c_{k,n,t} \equiv ln(\frac{\sum_{n=1}^N c_{k,n,t} }{\sum_{n=1}^N c_{k,n,t-1} })$.

Then average aggregate consumption growth follows to be:

\begin{equation}
Average AggregateConsumptionGrowth=\sum^K_{k=1} \sum^T_{t=2} \frac{\Delta \sum_{n=1}^N c_{k,n,t}}{K \times (T-1)}
\end{equation}

So the question is what are the properties of the relation between:

### $\sum^K_{k=1} \sum^T_{t=2} \frac{\Delta \sum_{n=1}^N c_{k,n,t}}{K \times (T-1)}$ and $\sum^K_{k=1} \sum^N_{n=1} \sum^T_{t=2} \frac{\Delta c_{k,n,t}}{K \times N \times (T-1)}$

Can one term be negative and the other positive? What drives the differences between the two terms?

Comment: Although I personally appreciate the context provided for the question, might this not be best suited to math stack with the just the last line generalised and the context removed?

Comment: @Attack68, it didn't get much traction there unfortunately. And here I can actually give a bounty to an answer in a few hours :)

Comment: Could this also be something for the Economics forum?